# Initializing an existing web application with mobile

Tags: flash, apache-flex, air

I've created a working web/desktop application om flash builder 4.6  and moved all the code to a library except for the main mxml that initializes the application. Now I need to build a mobile version using the shared library. How would I initialize the app with mobile? the mobile in this case is android.

here is the code initializing the web/desktop version, I basically need the mobile version of this:

```
      <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
               xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
           xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" width="800"     minHeight="600"
               backgroundColor="0x000000"     applicationComplete="initialApplication()">

            <![CDATA[
                import com.dga.MainStage;



            private function initialApplication():void {

                var mainStage:MainStage = new MainStage();
                this.addElement(mainStage);
            }
        ]]> 
</s:Application>
```

Comment: I cant see anything in your code that needs changing - just publish it as an AIR for Android app (you may need to manually import mx.swc into included libraries if you are using mx components - what IDE are you using?)

Comment: @Lee Burrows, Thanks for the quick reply. I'm using Adobe Flash Builder.

Comment: Harry I'm with Lee on this one. Is there a problem with how you are initializing it when trying to make this work in a mobile app  IF not; why wouldn't you do the exact same thing?